# how to use JodaTime to see if current time is 4pm

Tags: java, android, jodatime

How can I use `JodaTime` to see if the current hour is `16` ?

Currently I have this code and it's not working

```
    if (DateTime.now().getHourOfDay() == 19 &&  DateTime.now().getMinuteOfDay() == 44 ){
        Toast.makeText(context, "It's 7:44pm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("onReceive", "It's 7:44pm");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to use

```
DateTime.now().getMinuteOfHour();
```

instead of

```
DateTime.now().getMinuteOfDay();
```

I think the difference is quite obvious (minute of day vs. minute of hour). The rest of your code (especially DateTime.now().getHourOfDay() == 19 is correct).